# How do I combine two files containing simple lists?

Tags: list, merge, noscript

For Google Chrome browser, I'm using an extension called NotScripts which allows you to only enable javascript for sites you put on the whitelist (and the opposite using blacklists). Since there's no cloud account for merging several instances of NotScripts across my platforms, I have to do this manually.

Thus, I have copied and pasted the whitelist from one instance of NotScripts on OSX Google Chrome into a text file called whitelist-a.txt and the other instance of NotScripts from Windows Google Chrome into a text file called whitelist-b.txt.

whitelist-a.txt -

```
10.0.0.1
192.168.1.1
192.168.100.1
instagr.am
google.com.au
mathiasbynens.be
google.ca
thisisphotography.ca
cyberduck.ch
google.com.co
ideaware.co
0to255.com
20thingsilearned.com
456bereastreet.com
[...]
```

whitelist-b.txt -

```
10.0.0.1
192.168.1.1
instagr.am
marblerun.at
google.com.au
thisisphotography.ca
cyberduck.ch
keithcakes.com.au
yellowshoe.com.au
mathiasbynens.be
gorealty.biz
monzilla.biz
cbc.ca
google.ca
[...]
```

As you can see, there are some similarities between the two lists. I don't want to merge the lists so that `list a` overwrites `list b`, but i want the two lists to become one, such as the following:

```
10.0.0.1
192.168.1.1
192.168.100.1
instagr.am
marblerun.at
google.com.au
mathiasbynens.be
google.ca
thisisphotography.ca
cyberduck.ch
keithcakes.com.au
yellowshoe.com.au
goreality.biz
monzilla.biz
google.com.co
google.ca
ideaware.co
cbc.ca
0to255.com
20thingsilearned.com
456bereastreet.com
[...]
```

Are there problems or scripts I can run to do this? I'm not well versed in line command and can't find any plugins or scripts to do this either.

Comment: I don't think you want the noscript tag - please review.

Comment: Sorry dude, but I had to vote the question down as it has nothing to do with Programming or Programming Environment.  SO is not the place for How to on non programing related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out NotScripts will automatically match and discard matching domains so that it only appears once. So, to easily combine, I just pasted one list on top of the other and NotScripts did all the hard work.